# Dockerizing existing application

Tags: docker

I am completely new to docker and i am not a developer. Right now i have an application which runs on `centos/nginx/dotnetcore` . In `dotnet core` i have 4 applications, we run them using `dotnet appname.dll.` or rather `systemd`. If i want to dockerize this application set, should i create centos as a separate `docker` image and then nginx as other image and then an image for each of the application ? If yes how do i link them, or should i create only one image with `centos/nginx` and all 4 applications (which is in tar) installed? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple images is preferred, yes. Per microservice/process and per application. The documentation calls this [decoupling applications](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications). Say that nginx is a proxy container, in front of a dotnetcore app container. For each of 4 applications.

It is common to build containers based on official ones, like nginx or [dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-runtime/). Microsoft has [procedures to build .NET core Docker images](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images) and [samples in the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/aspnetapp).

These images may not be based on CentOS, but standardizing on a distro isn't necessary. All you need is a minimal set of binaries to run your thing. Like a chroot, if that is more familiar to you than containers.

Linking a proxy to the app can be done in several ways, depending on how you decide to implement container networking. For example, Kubernetes can define services and provide [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) proxies in front of them. In this design, an application nginx container may not be necessary, if the service is provided by the container orchestrator.